# another way to write this

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there another way to write this:

```
//javascript and jquery area
'<% if (Model.Fruit == MyEnum.Apple) { %>'
         $("#PaymentType option").each(function(){
                //blah
         });
'<% }  %>'
```

i'm not sure i like the quotes around the whole if statement

Comment: Can you clarify? What is the intended purpose of the quoting? Is it just a Visual Studio validation warning you are trying to avoid?

Comment: if i remove the quotes then i lose javascript syntax checker (you know how when you type the end brace } it will try to reformat the code and it's also a subtle indication to me that something is wrong in the script. Also it gives me the green squiggly line at the end of my script as if something is wrong and really there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
var isApple = <% Model.Fruit == MyEnum.Apple %>;
```

In an included javascript file:

```
if(isApple) {
    $("#PaymentType option").each(function(){
        //blah
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have VS continue to correctly check/auto-reformat javascript then you must use your trick or one similar to avoid the issue.

In one of the answers to the following related question there is text from Microsoft indicating that this is a known issue for which they do not yet have a good solution.

[Visual Studio confused by server code inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983477/visual-studio-confused-by-server-code-inside-javascript)