# Jquery get property from C# has warning in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a property in the aspx.cs page:

```
public string UtilizatorLogat 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return (!(Session["utilizator"] == null)).ToString().ToLower(); 
    } 
}
```

And I get it in the aspx page, on $(document).ready:

```
utilizatorLogat = <%=UtilizatorLogat%>;
```

But visual studio says: **Syntax Error**.

I cannot include it in `""` because it's a boolean value and I don't want to make it a string one...

Any ideas why is this warning shown?

Comment: You could do `utilizatorLogat = '<%=UtilizatorLogat%>' == 'True';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error to the JavaScript parser, which doesn't think `<%=UtilizatorLogat%>` is valid. This is a common problem when mixing client/server code.

One way you can work around this is to quote the value, but then parse or test it (in JavaScript) to a boolean.

```
var utilizatorLogat = /true/i.test("<%=UtilizatorLogat%>");
```

When the page renders, it will be:

```
var utilizatorLogat = /true/i.test("false");
```

It looks strange, but this way you avoid syntax errors in the designer which can also cause problems with automatic formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to string if you want to use it with on client side

```
var utilizatorLogat =<%=UtilizatorLogat.ToString().ToLower()%>;
```

You can use this trick too to avoid warnings:

original code:

```
   <script type="Text/javascript">
    <%If Page.IsPostback Then%>
    alert("my javascript code");
    <%End If%>
    </script>
```

solution:

```
<script type="Text/javascript">
//<%If Page.IsPostback Then%>
alert("my javascript code");
//<%End If%>
</script>
```

Reference: [Visual Studio confused by server code inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983477/visual-studio-confused-by-server-code-inside-)

Answer (score 0):

I think is a mix between Adriano and Phx answer (Adriano don't put the quotes)
I use always this kind of solution and it works

```
var utilizatorLogat ='<%=UtilizatorLogat.ToString().ToLower()%>';
```